# How to find a saddle point of a matrix using Java?

Tags: java

How can I find a saddle point of a matrix, which is the highest number in the row and at the same time the highest number in column using Java?

For example, using this matrix:

| 7   2 |

| 1   3 |

| 5   8 |

the saddle points are: 7 and 8.

Here is the portion of my code I wrote to find the highest number in the row and in the column.

```
int NumRow = 3;    
int NumCol = 2;
int [] matrix = new int [NumRow][NumCol];

for ( int i = 0; i < NumRow; i++) 
{
    max = matrix[i][0];

    for ( int j = 1; j < NumCol; j++) 
    {
        if (matrix[i][j]> max) 
        {
            max = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.print(max+"  ");

}
System.out.println("\n");

for ( int c = 0; c < NumCol; c++)
{
    largest = matrix[c][0];

    for (int r = 0; r < NumRow; r++){
        if (matrix[r][c] > largest){
            largest = matrix[r][c];
        }
    }
    System.out.print(largest+"  ");   
}
```

The output is:

7  3  8

7  8

Now I want to find the saddle point using the definition above.

Comment: that is a very strange definition of saddle point. are you sure it is the correct definition?

Comment: Why not just track them while iterating the multi dimensional array?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Are you wondering about the structure of your program?

Comment: i need help in looping through the matrix and display those two numbers. i wrote a for loop that will go through each row and column and find the highest. but, i got stuck after that.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com). StackOverflow is not a "do-my-coding-work-for-me" place. You need to show some effort; you need to show us what you have tried to solve your problem by yourself, and then ask for help on the specific problems that you are facing.

Comment: OP, please show us what you have so far, and please change your question to have a correct definition of a saddle point and i'm sure people will try to help you out.

Comment: NutterzUK: for the other definition, i found many examples that demonstrate how to find the saddle point. however, i want to find the saddle point using the def. i gave.

Comment: Ok user308461. That's fine. The first thing I would do is get yours to compile and then start working from there. You need to define the 'i' variable and also NumRow and NumCol. Are you sure they want to go that way around?

Comment: The saddle point with in matrix is not the value at this specific point, but its coordinate. In your case, because 7 and 8 are occurring only once, it still kinda works though... :) But nevertheless, it is incorrect to say that "7" is a saddle point of this matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I have to go. It looks like you were going to get there in the end.
Here is a solution which is based on your description, and the way you describe it should work.

It's not the most efficient, you should improve that. You also should not submit this as an assignment, doing so would only be cheating yourself, you will find future assignments difficult.

```
public class SaddlePointerFinder{

    public static void main(String[] args){

       int [] [] matrix = {   
        { 7, 2 },
        { 1, 3 },
        { 5, 8 },
       };

       // i loops though columns
       for(int x = 0; x<matrix[0].length; x++){    

       // this is to store the highest on the ROW
        int highestOnTheRow = -1;
       // this is to store the index of that highest value
       int indexOfHighest = -1;

       // x loops through rows
       for(int y = 0; y<matrix.length; y++){
            if(matrix[y][x] > highestOnTheRow) {
                // update the highest
                highestOnTheRow = matrix[y][x];
                indexOfHighest = y;
            }
        }

        // After checking the whole row and finding the highest, check if it's highest on the column
        boolean highest = true;

        // here, i checks goes through each row using that column.
        for(int i = 0; i<matrix[0].length; i++){
            if(matrix[indexOfHighest][i] > highestOnTheRow) {
                // one which was higher was found :(
                highest = false;
            }
        }
        if(highest){
               System.out.println("If the forumla is correct, this is a saddle point: " + highestOnTheRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way this is not according to the definition of saddle point as on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point A saddle point is an element of the matrix which is both the largest element in its column and the smallest element in its row. see here

Answer (score 3):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) (emphasis mine):

> A saddle point is an element of the matrix which is both the **largest**
>   element in its column and the **smallest** element in its row.

You can determine it by going through the matrix in row-order and:

- creating an array to store the current-column maximum
- storing a current-row-**minimum** on the fly and store it in an array too

when you are done with this you can compare if an index occurs in both at the same time so that you have an index which is both the column-max and row-min.

Note: your example-matrix does not have any saddle points according to wikipedia's definition.

Comment: That seems pretty clear. So, by that definition, wouldn't the saddle points given by the question author be incorrect? Actually, this seems impossible, given the set of numbers above. For example, 8 is the largest element in its column, but also the largest element in its row.

Comment: @crush the question-author thought it was the **max** both times.

Comment: What would be the saddle points in the authors matrix? 7 and 8 don't seem to fit the wikipedia definition. I can't seem to find any numbers that do.

Comment: @crush in his matrix-example there are no saddle-points.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't going crazy.

Comment: Yes, largest element in the column = 7 and 8. Smallest in their rows = 2 and 5. By this definition, there is no saddle point.

Comment: I created a solution based on the OPs version of what a saddle point is which works, but since that doesn't solve the REAL problem, and since the OP needs to show some effort him/her self, it won't be posted :(.

Comment: @NutterzUK :-) you can post it later for future reference

Comment: i know it's very strange that the definition i gave does not match with what Wikipedia definition says. however, it's very challenging to find the saddle point in the definition i gave before.

Comment: @user3080461 also your algorithm is inefficient: for each cell going through each row and each column. If you like it try to implement what I described.