# How to find the saddlePoint in IntMatrix

Tags: java, methods, point, saddle

This is my program in finding the Saddle Point of a Matrix (IntMatrix). Please help me make another method for IntMatrix m, for the Parameters inside the saddlePoints method?

```
public class SaddlePoint{
    public void saddlePoints(IntMatrix m, int[] rows, int[] cols) {
        int rows = m.length;
        int cols = m[0].length;

        boolean[][] flagArr = new boolean[rows][cols];

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                if(m[i][j]==0){
                    flagArr[i][j]=true;
                }
            }
        } 

        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                if(flagArr[i][j]==true){
                    /*for rows*/
                    for(int k=0; k<rows; k++){
                        m[k][j]=0;
                    }
                    /*for cols*/
                    for(int z=0; z<cols; z++){
                        m[i][z]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**this is the requirement
but i need the saddlePoint method only because I already have the other methods**

```
IntMatrix Class:
 //represents a 2-dimensional matrix of integers
    Constructor Signature:
        IntMatrix(int rows, int cols, int ... elements)
        //elements are provided in row major order

IntMatrixUtilityClass
    Static Methods:
        IntMatrix sum(IntMatrix ... matrices)
        //returns the sum of its arguments

        IntMatrix product(IntMatrix m1, IntMatrix m2, IntMatrix ... others)
        //returns the product of its arguments

        boolean[] saddlePoints(IntMatrix m, int[] rows, int[] cols)
        /*for each of the row and column pairs, returns true if the specified element of m is a saddle
        point for the matrix; returns false otherwise*/
```

**this is my program, I only need the saddlePoints**

```
public class IntMatrix {
  private int[][] matrix;
  private int rows;
  private int cols;
  private int[] elements;

public IntMatrix(int r, int c, int... e) {
    this.rows = r;
    this.cols = c;
    this.elements = e;

    matrix = new int[rows][cols];
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            this.matrix[i][j] = elements[l];
            l++;
        }
    }
}

public static IntMatrix sum(IntMatrix... matrices) {
    int[] result = new int[matrices[0].rows * matrices[0].cols];
    for (IntMatrix matrix : matrices) {
        int l = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.cols; j++) {
                result[l] += matrix.matrix[i][j];
                l++;
            }
        }
    }

    IntMatrix m3 = new IntMatrix(matrices[0].rows, matrices[0].cols, result);

    return m3;
}

public static IntMatrix product(IntMatrix m1, IntMatrix m2,
        IntMatrix... others) {

    int[] result = new int[m1.rows * m2.cols];
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m1.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m2.cols; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m1.cols; k++) {
                result[l] += (m1.matrix[i][k] * m2.matrix[k][j]);
            }
            l++;
        }
    }
    IntMatrix m3 = new IntMatrix(m1.rows, m2.cols, result);

    for (IntMatrix other : others) {
        int length = others.length;
        l = 0;
        int[] result2 = new int[(m3.rows * others[length - 1].cols)];
        for (int i = 0; i < m3.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < other.cols; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < m3.cols; k++) {
                    result2[l] += (m3.matrix[i][k] * other.matrix[k][j]);
                }
                l++;
            }
        }
        m3 = new IntMatrix(m3.rows, others[length - 1].cols, result2);
    }

    return m3;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(rows) + " " + " " + String.valueOf(cols)
            + Arrays.toString(elements);
}

}// end of Matrix Class
```

Comment: can you tell me or give me code of IntMatrix

Comment: The accepted Answer on that link is wrong. it is not according to the defination of seadle point. @StephMarry0812 also required seadle point . i have done this but here requirement is littel different and StephMarry is also new to programming i think :)

Comment: @Mubasher If the accepted answer there is wrong, fix it... It's still a duplicate.

Comment: @Unihedron i cant post there as question was closed due to off topic. i am posting here my code according to wikipedia defination

Comment: I think marking this ans as duplicate is wrong.in pointed link The marked answer is wrong there according to saddle point in matrix rule. So this guy did not deserve this. But i agree that this person clearly did not research before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

First I want to say please do some research on your own before asking. From Here [How to find a saddle point of a matrix using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338735/how-to-find-a-saddle-point-of-a-matrix-using-java) you can find accepted ans but here I tell you that is not according to [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)

## Sadle Point:

```
A saddle point is an element of the matrix which is both the largest element in its 
column and the smallest element in its row.
```

OR in simple words A matrix is said to have a saddle point if some entry a[x][y] is the smallest value in the x'th row and the largest value in the y'th column. A matrix may have more than one saddle point.

This Code is according to wikipedia defination

```
package com.mubasher.main;

import java.util.Random;

public class SaddlePoint {

private int[][] intMatrix;
private int[] colMaxima;
private int[] rowMinima;
public SaddlePoint(int col, int row){
    intMatrix = new int[row][col];
    colMaxima = new int[col];
    rowMinima = new int[row];
    fillMatrix();
}
private void fillMatrix() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int row = 0; row<intMatrix.length;row++){
        for(int col = 0;col<intMatrix[0].length;col++){
            intMatrix[row][col] = random.nextInt(21) - 10;
        }
    }
    printMatrix();
}
private void printMatrix(int[][] intMatrix) {
    for(int row = 0;row<intMatrix.length;row++){
        for(int col = 0; col<intMatrix[0].length;col++){
            System.out.print(intMatrix[row][col]+"   ");
        }
        System.out.println("");         
    }
    for(int i=0;i<intMatrix[0].length;i++)
    System.out.print("----");
    System.out.println("");
}
public void printMatrix() {
    printMatrix(intMatrix);
}
public void printArray(int[] array,boolean isHorizontaly) {
    for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(isHorizontaly){
            System.out.print(array[i]+"   ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    if(isHorizontaly){System.out.println("");
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        System.out.print("----");
    } else {
        System.out.println("----");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public void run(){
    int maxVal = 0,minVal=0;
    //minimum in each row
    for(int row = 0; row<intMatrix.length;row++){
        for(int col = 0;col<intMatrix[0].length;col++){
            if(col == 0 ) {
                rowMinima[row]=intMatrix[row][col]; // assume first val at (row,0) is minimum 
            } else {
                if(intMatrix[row][col]<rowMinima[row]){
                    rowMinima[row]=intMatrix[row][col]; // assign new minimum val
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //maximum in each column
    for(int col = 0; col<intMatrix[0].length;col++){
        for(int row = 0;row<intMatrix.length;row++){
            if(row == 0 ) {
                colMaxima[col]=intMatrix[row][col]; // for 
            } else {
                if(intMatrix[row][col]>colMaxima[col]){
                    colMaxima[col]=intMatrix[row][col]; // assign new max val
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printArray(colMaxima,true);
    printArray(rowMinima,false);
    int colIndx=0,rowIndx=0;
    for(int i =0;i<colMaxima.length;i++){
        if(i == 0 ) {
            minVal= colMaxima[i];
            colIndx=i;
        } else {
            if(colMaxima[i]<minVal){                    
                minVal= colMaxima[i];
                colIndx=i;
            } 
        }

    }
    for(int i =0;i<rowMinima.length;i++){
        if(i == 0 ) {
            maxVal= rowMinima[i];
            rowIndx = i;
        } else {
            if(rowMinima[i]>maxVal){
                maxVal= rowMinima[i];
                rowIndx = i;
            } 
        }

    }
    if(minVal == maxVal){
        System.out.println("We Have Saddle Point "+maxVal+" at ("+(rowIndx+1)+","+(colIndx+1)+")");
    } else {
        System.out.println("There is no saddle point");
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SaddlePoint sp = new SaddlePoint(3, 4);
    sp.run();
}

}
```

you can modify run method according to your needs. run method is calculating saddle point

Comment: Thanks but I need a method for intMatrix.. I am required to use the parameters (IntMatrix m, int[] rows, int[] cols). I did some research but can't find any..

Comment: I posted here the requirements i need in my program